# C# convert to date - No implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and '<null>'

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
      var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
      DateAnalyzed_Copper = records.DateAnalyzed_Copper.HasValue ? TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(records.DateAnalyzed_Copper.Value, tz) : null,
```

......

Note that DateAnalyzed_Copper is a nullable DateTime.

I get the following message

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and '<null>'
```

Comment: Not a downvoter but you could have boiled it down to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) such as: `? new DateTime() : null`. Lines like `var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");` clearly have nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast either `null` to nullable DateTime:

```
DateAnalyzed_Copper = records.DateAnalyzed_Copper.HasValue ? 
   TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(records.DateAnalyzed_Copper.Value, tz)  
   : (DateTime?)null
```

Or `DateTime` value returned by `ConvertTimeToUtc`:

```
DateAnalyzed_Copper = records.DateAnalyzed_Copper.HasValue ? 
  (DateTime?)TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(records.DateAnalyzed_Copper.Value, tz)
  : null
```

Ternary operator needs either same types on both branches, or there should be implicit conversion between them. You have different types, and there is no implicit converstion between `DateTime` and `null`. So, you shoul use explicit one.

Comment: So, just cast the NULL to a Nullable DateTime indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is stating that the explicit value of `null` is not a valid `DateTime` value; you can either cast null to a `DateTime` via:

```
(DateTime?)null
```

or use C#'s [`default()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx):

```
default(DateTime)
```

Example:

```
DateAnalyzed_Copper = records.DateAnalyzed_Copper.HasValue ? 
    TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(records.DateAnalyzed_Copper.Value, tz) : 
    default(DateTime);
```

Alternatively, though I'm not a fan of this method, you can declare your `DateAnalyzedCopper` variable as nullable when you first create it:

```
DateTime? DateAnalyzedCopper;
```